# How to embed restrictions on token transfers after pancakeswap sale?

Tags: solidity, bsc, pancakeswap

I want to list a coin on pancakeswap (BEP20) that restricts people from selling for a period of time after purchasing. I don't want to restrict the pancakeswap address from being able to sell its tokens however. How would I do this?

Comment: Why are doing that? You can use some kind of whitelist to handle permissions.

Comment: I too wanted to achieve this, but have resigned my efforts.
I'm not an expert, but i beleive a hodle function needs to be hard coded into the smartchain contract. I am not sure if this could be done, as a solidity coder recently told me that restricting a sell for an amount of time was not possible. What I beleive would be possible, is creating your own token wallet that restricts sells per transaction address. This would be costly though.